# Read Image from hbase and detect faces in that image using Opencv

Tags: opencv, hadoop, hbase, hipi

I need to read images in hbase and convert to `opencv` mat for face detection. 
My code as follows

```
public static class FaceCountMapper extends TableMapper<Text, Text> {
private CascadeClassifier faceDetector;

public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    if (context.getCacheFiles() != null && context.getCacheFiles().length > 0) {
        URI mappingFileUri = context.getCacheFiles()[0];

        if (mappingFileUri != null) {
            System.out.println(mappingFileUri);
            faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(mappingFileUri.toString());

        }
    }

    super.setup(context);
} // setup()

public ArrayList<Object> detectFaces(Mat image, String file_name) {

    ArrayList<Object> facemap = new ArrayList<Object>();

    MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();

    faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);

    System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));
    output.put(faceDetections.toArray().length);

    facemap.add(output);

}

return facemap;

}

public void map(ImmutableBytesWritable row, Result result, Context context)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    String file_name = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("Filename"), Bytes.toBytes("data")));

    String mimetype = Bytes.toString(result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("mime"), Bytes.toBytes("data")));

    byte[] image_data = result.getValue(Bytes.toBytes("Data"), Bytes.toBytes("data"));

    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image_data));

    Mat mat = new Mat(bi.getHeight(), bi.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);

    mat.put(0, 0, image_data);
    detectFaces(mat, file_name);

}
```

Job configuration as follows

```
Configuration conf = this.getConf();
    conf.set("hbase.master", "101.192.0.122:16000");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "101.192.0.122");
    conf.setInt("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", 2181);
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");

    // Initialize and configure MapReduce job
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);

    job.setJarByClass(FaceCount3.class);
    job.setMapperClass(FaceCountMapper.class);
    job.getConfiguration().set("fs.hdfs.impl", org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.class.getName());
    job.getConfiguration().set("fs.file.impl", org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem.class.getName());

    Scan scan = new Scan();
    scan.setCaching(500); // 1 is the default in Scan, which will be bad for
                            // MapReduce jobs
    scan.setCacheBlocks(false); // don't set to true for MR jobs

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob("Image", // input HBase table name
            scan, // Scan instance to control CF and attribute selection
            FaceCountMapper.class, // mapper
            null, // mapper output key
            null, // mapper output value
            job);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(NullOutputFormat.class); // because we aren't
                                                        // emitting anything
                                                        // from mapper

    job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/hduser/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"));
    job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/hduser/hipi-2.1.0.jar"));
    job.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/hduser/javacpp.jar"));
    DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(new Path("/user/hduser/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"), conf);
    conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");
    // Execute the MapReduce job and block until it complets
    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);

    // Return success or failure
    return success ? 0 : 1;
```

When running I am getting

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier.CascadeClassifier_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J

error.

But Opencv.jar provide in hadoop_classpath

Answer (score 1):

The UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown when an application attempts to load a native library like `.so` in Linux, `.dll` on Windows or `.dylib` in Mac and that library does not exist. Specifically, in order to find the required native library, the JVM looks in both the PATH environment variable and the `java.library.path` system property.

**Moreover, in case the library is already loaded by your application and the application tries to load it again, the `UnsatisfiedLinkError` will be thrown by the JVM.** Also, you must verify that the native library is present either in the java.library.path or in the PATH environment library of your application. If the library still cannot be found, try to provide an absolute path to the System.loadLibrary method.

In your case, please try below method from caller and see what are the classpath elements.

```
/**
     * Method printClassPathResources.
     */
    public static void printClassPathResources() {
        final ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        final URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
        LOG.info("Print All Class path resources under currently running class");
        for (final URL url : urls) {
            LOG.info(url.getFile());
        }

    }
```

based on these inputs you can adjust your classpath entries ( in this case opencv jar or something) and see whether working.

Comment: There is no problem with library because in Main class static method, I used System.loadLibaray method to load opencv.so file

Comment: pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625948/opencv-java-unsatisfiedlinkerror I dont know much about opencv. But surely that was approach discussed by many others

Comment: Yes, after reinstalling hipi, opencv in machine what is the problem.Thanks @RamPrasad G