# Jar files with parameters and classpath variable

Tags: java, opencv, jar, console

I'm trying to start my jar-file on a debian in a console. It gets 5 parameters, which look like is shown in the following peace of code:

```
     if (args.length!=5) { 
       System.out.println("Usage: java popscan.Waterflood" 
                       + " [source image filename]" 
                       + " [destination image filename]" 
                       + " [flood point count (1-256)]" 
                       + " [minimums window width (8-256)]" 
                       + " [connected pixels (4 or 8)]" 
                       ); 
       return; 
   }
```

Another part is that it requires the class path to an external library which in this case is OpenCV.

My question is how to start it correctly. I tried a few combinations like:

user@server:~/Waterflood$ java -jar WaterFlood.jar 1.png 1res.png 2 8 8 -cp ~/opencv/installed opencv 3.1/opencv-3.1.0/build/bin/opencv-310.jar

But I always get the message:

```
Usage: java popscan.Watershed [source image filename] [destination image filename] [flood point count (1-256)] [minimums window width (8-256)] [connected pixels (4 or 8)]
```

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `-cp ...jar` to directly after java. It's not an argument to the program, it's for the java virtual machine.

```
java -cp "~/opencv/installed opencv 3.1/opencv-3.1.0/build/bin/opencv-310.jar" -jar WaterFlood.jar 1.png 1res.png 2 8 8
```

Comment: Yes, but then i get: "Error: Could not find or load main class opencv"

Comment: You are probably getting bittne by those spaces as well, make sure you enclose that argument with `"`

Comment: I get the following problem: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path

Comment: I did update the answer. Now you have a different problem, regarding the use of opencv, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625948/opencv-java-unsatisfiedlinkerror