# OpenCV 3.0 for Android - static initialization not loading new modules

Tags: android, opencv

I recently moved my Android project from OpenCV 2.4.10 to **OpenCV 3.0**.

I statically initialize OpenCV using this code:

```
OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
```

When I run my app, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1:(Ljava/lang/String;)J
```

Imgcodecs is a new module in OpenCV 3.0 which replaces Highgui from OpenCV 2.4.* if I am right.

I can see following output in logs from OpenCV when it initializes:

```
Version control:               2.4.10
...
To be built:                 core androidcamera flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml objdetect video contrib photo java legacy ocl stitching superres ts videostab
```

**From the information above I guess that the OpenCVLoader of OpenCV 3.0 initializes only the old modules from 2.4.10.** You can see that it loads highgui module which should not be needed anymore.

Is this a bug of new OpenCV or am I missing something? Is there some workaround how to load also the new modules? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939192/unsatisfied-link-error-opencv-for-android-non-native

Comment: I saw that and I do not think it is related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems working now using the updated version from 23.6.2015.

The error seems to have been fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/83b2621de4a53506afcd47b69fac210534304fe3), so the answer is that the problem was probably caused by an OpenCV bug.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that make a new project, add opencv static version, import build.gradle and change the version from 2.4.* to 3.0.* 
I did the same, my previous version was 2.4.9 and after migration this is 3.0.0

```
To be Built: hal core flann imgproc ml photo video ***imgcodecs*** shape videoio ..
```

As this is obvious in your project, you are still on version 2.4.*