# Am I accessing file correctly?

Tags: java, android, opencv

This is the code I'm trying to use

```
File filePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/test.bmp");
String file = filePath.getAbsolutePath();
Mat input_mat = Highgui.imread(file);
```

When I use the app with the last line it crashes. I'm not sure if the last line is the mistake or if I'm not accessing the test.bmp file properly. Its saved on the root of the sdcard.

It is for an android app on eclipse.

**edit logcat**

```
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: imread_1
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread_1(Native Method)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.imread(Highgui.java:324)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.example.android.photobyintent.PhotoIntentActivity.dispatchProcVideoIntent(PhotoIntentActivity.java:186)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.example.android.photobyintent.PhotoIntentActivity.access$2(PhotoIntentActivity.java:182)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.example.android.photobyintent.PhotoIntentActivity$4.onClick(PhotoIntentActivity.java:264)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-11 22:38:50.288: E/AndroidRuntime(545):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the error message from logcat that you're seeing when the app crashes?

Comment: This isn't related to your problem, but I thought I'd mention that the leading '/' isn't needed in the filename, the "new File()" constructor will add it for you.  Second, it's bad style to put files in the top level of the SD card; it can get very cluttered that way.  You should create an application-specific directory for your files.

Comment: Are you sure you just dont have permission to access the SDCard?

Comment: I added logcat. And yes, I have a directory for the file, but when I had errors the first time, I tried moving to root.

Comment: Looks like the Highgui library is calling into a native library that's not present on your system.  There's probably a required .so file that's missing.  It's also likely that you won't be able to install it on your device.  Are there any known instances of anybody ever getting Highgui to work on Android?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with reading of the bitmap file. `UnsatisfiedLinkError` means it wasn't able to find the shared objects (`.so` files) implementing that class. It means something is wrong with your project configuration. Did you copy the required files to `libs/armeabi`, `libs/armeabi-v7a` and `libs/x86`?

Also see:

[Android for OpenCV - error opening trace file, UnsatisfiedLinkError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852642/android-for-opencv-error-opening-trace-file-unsatisfiedlinkerror)

Comment: I didn't. I can only see android-support-v4.jar in there. No armeabi armeabi-v7a or x86. What are the "required files" I need to add?

Comment: They should be in the SDK you download. Follow the instructions on http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html

Comment: I found armeabi-v7a x86 and mips but not armeabi. I added them but get the same error. Anything else I can try?

Comment: Download the correct SDK and get the `armeabi` version too from `sdk/native/libs`. I have no better tip than to follow that tutorial. It has step by step instructions that result in a working project. If that fails, add a list of all the files in your project so it can be verified.

Comment: I'm using v2.2 and couldn't find those files. So I tried v2.4.3 and the files were there but I get the same error.

Comment: Did you follow the entire tutorial? Did you try the first link I posted?

Comment: Yes I made a new workspace with that sdk and the imported by program then copied the files from native/libs.